# Magento - Pagination with different number of elements displayed depending on the page number

Tags: zend-framework, magento, pagination, zend-db

I'm trying to achieve a non-standart behaviour in magento; Within products categories, I basically need to display a different number of products depending on the current page number.
I'm not quite sure that I can specify this just by a configuration settings in magento admin.

So I suppose I will need to hook into magento core to achieve this.
Any recommandation on where to start this / how to override default behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Added Zend tags because Magento's paging behaviour is inherited from Zend; It multiplies page size by page number for you so getting different page sizes is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'll have to override the _getProductCollection method in Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List in order to achieve that.